# divs are not placed on the same height as their neighbour divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when I place my div containers in one row, they are not placed on the same height. You can see it, when using my fiddle on a larger field of view. So try out full page or something like this.

I used `display:inline-block;` because I want them to be in a row. When the window gets smaller, they should start a new row on their own.

```js
function record(title, description){ 
    // record object
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

function init(){
    var records = []; // array of all record objects
 
  // fill the Data -> test routine
    var foo = "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et earebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, n"
    var bar = " labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et";
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        records.push(new record("title " + i, i % 2 == 0 ? foo : bar));
    }
        
    // build up the view
    $(records).each(function (index, currentRecord) {
        var recordContainer = $("<div></div>"); // parent container
        recordContainer.addClass("recordContainer");
        $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

        var title = $("<div>" + currentRecord.title + "</div>"); // title div
        title.addClass("recordTitle");
        recordContainer.append(title);

        var description = $("<div>" + currentRecord.description + "</div>"); // text div
        description.addClass("recordDescription");
        recordContainer.append(description);
    });
}

init(); // run the code ...
```

```css
body{background-color: #262626;}

.recordContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #373737;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.recordContainer:hover{
    background-color: #484848;
}

.recordContainer:hover .recordTitle{
    color: #7dd7ef;
}

.recordTitle{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #5bb5cd;
}

.recordDescription{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try adding `vertical-align: top;` (or bottom or middle) to `.recordContainer{` - it works but I don't know why exactly :p (something to do with the content of each of those inline blocks being a different height I think and the default vertical-align being `baseline`)

Comment: use `display: inline-table` instead of  `display: inline-block` for `.recordContainer`. It should be what you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;` on your `.recordContainer` class.

```
.recordContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #373737;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your recordContainer:

`vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add `vertical-align: top;`

```js
function record(title, description){ // record object
this.title = title;
this.description = description;
}

function init(){
 var records = []; // array of all record objects
 
 
     // fill the Data -> test routine
        var foo = "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et earebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, n"
        var bar = " labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et";
     for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {records.push(new record("title " + i, i % 2 == 0 ? foo : bar));}
        
        // build up the view
 
 $(records).each(function (index, currentRecord) {
            var recordContainer = $("<div></div>"); // parent container
            recordContainer.addClass("recordContainer");
            $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

            var title = $("<div>" + currentRecord.title + "</div>"); // title div
            title.addClass("recordTitle");
            recordContainer.append(title);

            var description = $("<div>" + currentRecord.description + "</div>"); // text div
            description.addClass("recordDescription");
            recordContainer.append(description);
        });
}

init(); // run the code ...
```

```css
body{background-color: #262626;}

.recordContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* fixes your problem */
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #373737;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.recordContainer:hover{
    background-color: #484848;
}

.recordContainer:hover .recordTitle{
    color: #7dd7ef;
}

.recordTitle{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #5bb5cd;
}

.recordDescription{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

display: inline-table property will help you

```
  .recordContainer{
        display: inline-table;
        width: 250px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #373737;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As each block has a different content height the `baseline` for the block is calculated differently - and the default vertical alignment is `baseline`

changing the div's vertical alignment to any of `top`, `bottom`, `middle`, `text-top` or `text-bottom` will mean that the blocks will be aligned vertically using the same reference point

example using `top`:

```js
function record(title, description){ // record object
this.title = title;
this.description = description;
}

function init(){
 var records = []; // array of all record objects
 
 
     // fill the Data -> test routine
        var foo = "invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et earebum.Stet clita kasd gubergren, n"
        var bar = " labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et";
     for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {records.push(new record("title " + i, i % 2 == 0 ? foo : bar));}
        
        // build up the view
 
 $(records).each(function (index, currentRecord) {
            var recordContainer = $("<div></div>"); // parent container
            recordContainer.addClass("recordContainer");
            $(document.body).append(recordContainer);

            var title = $("<div>" + currentRecord.title + "</div>"); // title div
            title.addClass("recordTitle");
            recordContainer.append(title);

            var description = $("<div>" + currentRecord.description + "</div>"); // text div
            description.addClass("recordDescription");
            recordContainer.append(description);
        });
}

init(); // run the code ...
```

```css
body{background-color: #262626;}

.recordContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #373737;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.recordContainer:hover{
    background-color: #484848;
}

.recordContainer:hover .recordTitle{
    color: #7dd7ef;
}

.recordTitle{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #5bb5cd;
}

.recordDescription{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```